# File uploading on localhost but not being uploaded after publishing on web server in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have code for File Upload. File is uploaded on local host but after publishing file does not get uploaded and it does not give any error.

Also I have changed the folder (upload and docchange) in IIS settings to full control, but file does not get uploaded.

```
If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    Dim name As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim location As String = Server.MapPath("~\upload\docchange\" & name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saved the file in that code plus use '/' not '\'

```
Dim name As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName)
Dim location As String = Server.MapPath("../upload/docchange")
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(location & "/" & name)
' You can use FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(location, name)) instead
```

When you run locally you are saving as a Windows User but online you aren't so you need to make sure the IUSR has write permissions to that directory. Is the Application Pool LocalSystem or NetworkService? Make sure it's LocalSystem. Also, if the posted file is over a certain size it will error. The file size needs to be changed in the web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" etc.
```